# Use sed to replace multiple special characters

Tags: linux, sed

I am looking to replace `http://${window.location.hostname}:8000/` by `http://localhost:6301`.

I tried with `sed -i 's/${window.location.hostname}:8000/localhost:6301/g' src/components/shared/services/config.js` but I get an error message `"bad substitution"`

Any idea, please?

---

My real [command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65886855/use-sed-to-replace-multiple-special-characters/65887434?noredirect=1#comment116493494_65887434) is:

```
sh 'sed -i "s/${window.location.hostname}:8000/localhost:6301/g" src/config/config.js'
```

Comment: I assume that you've mistyped 9092 or 6301.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use single quotes as shown in the question, you should not get a problem.

```
$ echo 'http://${window.location.hostname}:8000/' |
> /opt/gnu/bin/sed -e 's/${window.location.hostname}:8000/localhost:6301/g'
http://localhost:6301/
$
```

Since you used 6301 and not 9092 in the command, presumably that's the value you want.  If you want 9092 instead, write 9092 in the command.

If you use double quotes as shown below, you get a `bad substitution` error from the shell:

```
$ sed -e "s/${window.location.hostname}:8000/localhost:6301/g"
-bash: s/${window.location.hostname}:8000/localhost:6301/g: bad substitution
$
```

Note that the error message reports which program is identifying the error.  Since it says `-bash`, it's your login shell that is reporting the problem, not `sed`.  In fact, `sed` isn't even run because of the error.

Lessons to be learned:

- Use single quotes when possible.
- Be accurate in reporting your problems, including showing the entire error message.

---

> It does not work: `sh 'sed -i "s/${window.location.hostname}:8000/localhost:6301/g" src/config/config.js'` gives bad substitution.

That is a vastly more complex scenario than the one shown in the question.  You have two shells both interpreting the quotes and dollar signs.

You use single quotes around the command to prevent the first shell (your login shell) from expanding the `${…}` notation, but the second shell (the `sh -c` shell) then sees the double quotes and tries (but fails) to expand the `${…}` notation.  That means you must work harder.

This does the job:

```
$ echo 'http://${window.location.hostname}:8000/' |
> sh -c "sed -e 's/\${window.location.hostname}:8000/localhost:6301/g'"
http://localhost:6301/
$
```

When the login shell processes the argument string inside double quotes, the single quotes are not special, and the `\$` is mapped to `$`.  When the `sh -c` shell interprets the string, it sees `sed -e 's/${window.location.hostname}:8000/localhost:6301/g'` and the `$` is within single quotes and therefore not special.  You can see that by putting `echo` or `printf '%s\n'` in front of the word `sed`.

There are other ways to do it, but this is probably the simplest.  One alternative involves replacing every single quote in the command string with the sequence `'\''`.  In a single-quoted string, the first quote stops the current single quoting, the backslash-quote embeds a single quote, and the final quote restarts a single-quoted string.  You might therefore go through the sequence:

```
$ echo 'http://${window.location.hostname}:8000/' |
> sh -c 'sed -e '\''s/${window.location.hostname}:8000/localhost:6301/g'\'''
http://localhost:6301/
$ echo 'http://${window.location.hostname}:8000/' |
> sh -c 'sed -e '\''s/${window.location.hostname}:8000/localhost:6301/g'\'
http://localhost:6301/
$
```

The first of those is a mechanical translation of single quotes into the `'\''` sequence, ending with `''`.  That is an empty single-quoted string, though, and therefore pointless.  Hence the second version drops the trailing `''`.

Finally, observe that you say `sh 'sed -i …'`; that causes the inner shell to try to execute a command named `sed -i …`, and you won't have a file with that name, so you'd get a 'command not found' error.  I automatically inserted the `-c` without even noticing that you'd omitted it.  It was only when cleaning up that I realized there was this extra mistake, hidden behind the failing shell variable expansion.

Comment: not worked
sh 'sed -i "s/${window.location.hostname}:8000/localhost:6301/g" src/config/config.js' 
bad substitution

Comment: Youssef, you did exaclty how Jonathan Leffler told you not to do. Try to make the command work, then encolse it in a call to `sh`.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a special character which matches the end of the line. To literally match it, you should quote it.

```
echo 'http://${window.location.hostname}:8000/' |sed 's/\${window.location.hostname}:8000/localhost:6301/g'
```

Output:

```
http://localhost:6301/
```

Comment: `$` is only special when it can mean 'end of line'.  In the context `${window.…}`, it can't mean that and therefore represents itself — and does not need to be escaped.

Comment: Well, yes that's the case in BRE. But not all types of regular expression, so it's a good habit to quote it.

Comment: Respectfully disagree.  Please cite an RE package where `$` must be escaped when it is not at the end of something — as in this example.  The braces might need escaping sometimes (e.g. with GNU `sed` and the `-E` option), but I'm not aware of an RE package where escaping the dollar is necessary in this example.  Also, of course, `sed` uses (a mildly extended form of) BRE by default.

Comment: Well, I've never successfully read a RE documentation (probably my fault :)). But I've got these "counter examples", perhaps you can shed some light here if I've misunderstood anything. `echo '$f'|sed -E 's/$f/m/'` vs. `echo '$f'|sed -E 's/\$f/m/'`. On my machine (with GNU sed 4.5) the first example prints `$f`, the second example prints `m`.

Comment: Thank you. Curious behaviour from GNU `sed -E`.  I can reproduce (I have GNU `sed` 4.2.2 installed at the moment). It also reproduces with BSD (macOS) `sed -E`. I'm not sure where one goes to find the specification of the ERE notation used by these. But a counter-example was what I was seeking, and what you've provided. It's more than a little nasty, if you ask me, changing the way `sed` has worked since time immemorial (say 1983 for me, 1978 for the documentation). But then, `-E` is new since then. See POSIX [ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html).

Comment: The POSIX ERE specification says _"The `<dollar-sign>` shall be special when used as an anchor"._  In the examples, `$` is not being used as an anchor.  Therefore, the ERE supported by `sed -E` is not, in fact, POSIX ERE but some minor variation on the theme.  That complicates life, as ever.  Thanks for the heads up!  (Oh, and POSIX [`sed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) does not specify the `-E` option, or the `-i` option, or …)